# Topologies in $\mathcal{C}^\infty(M,N)$

Tags: gn.general-topology, differential-topology, mapping-space

Naively, one could topologise the set of smooth (ie $\mathcal{C}^\infty$) maps between two smooth manifolds $M \to N$ with the subspace topology $\mathcal{C}^\infty(M,N) \subseteq \mathcal{C}^0(M,N)$, where the usual compact-open topology is considered in  $\mathcal{C}^0(M,N)$.

Now, why are the weak/strong topologies in  $\mathcal{C}^\infty(M,N)$  considered instead? How different are they from the subspace topology as explained before? What are their advantages with respect to the subspace topology?

Comment: Peter Michor's "Convenient setting of global analysis" is a very densely written book, but answers your question in great generality.

Comment: Also very large portion of @AndrewStacey works are aimed at studying function spaces of smooth manifolds.

Comment: The book my Kriegl & Michor is of course very comprehensive, but a more down-to-earth reference is "Differential topology" by Hirsch (Springer, 1976).